# Java: Optimizing algorithm in game

Tags: java, android, algorithm, libgdx, scene2d

I'm creating a game (Java) with scene2d.

I wrote function for collision detection but I think it's  bad function. It looks bad.

How can I optimize it? Make faster and more beautiful.

```
private void deleteEnemies()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < getActors().size - 1; i++)
    {
        if(getActors().get(i) != null && getActors().get(i) instanceof Enemy)
        {
            ////////////////
            for (int j = 0; j < getActors().size - 1; j++)
            {
                if(getActors().get(j) != null && getActors().get(j) instanceof Ball)
                {
                    if (actorsIntersecting(getActors().get(i), getActors().get(j)))
                    {
                        getActors().get(i).remove();
                        getActors().get(j).remove();
                    }
                }
            }
            //////////////
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think its bad?

Comment: quick note - make sure this line is right: `j < getActors().size - 1` - it seems you may miss the last list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the models a bit, so they can test the intersection itself and then do the delete like that (probably it can still be improved)

```
private void deleteEnemies () {
    List<Actor> actors = getActors();
    List<Actor> toRemove = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    int actorsSize = actors.size();
    Actor first = null, second = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < actorsSize; ++i) {
        first = actors.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < actorsSize; ++j) {
            if(i == j) continue;
            second = actors.get(j);
            if(first.intersects(second)) {
                toRemove.add(first);
                toRemove.add(second);

            }
        }
    }
    actors.removeAll(toRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put `getActors().get(i)` in a variable, dont call it twice in the outer if
2. Same for `getActors().get(j)` in the inner if
3. use these variable in the most inner if's condition and body
4. save the size in a variable because now the `.size` function is being called on every iteration when the for condition is checked
5. You shouldn't use a size that can dynamically change during the loop for the loop condition (because you are removing items as you go) which brings us back to #4.
   Other than that its pretty much ok coding style perspective and I doubt you can make it more efficient than with what I told you (Other than using threads)

Answer (score 1):

1. Well, my first idea was to check only "nearest" enemies and not all of them. Somehow try to decrease size of that list.

<s>2. Second one - please check your and conditions in and one by one - now you are checking 2 conditions always. Try to put "heavier" if later, for example:</s>

from:

```
  if(getActors().get(i) != null && getActors().get(i) instanceof Enemy)
```

to:

```
if(getActors().get(i) != null) {
    if(getActors().get(i) instanceof Enemy)  {
       .....
    }
}
```

3. call your getActors().get(i) one time - save to variable.
4. I'm thinking why is it necessary to check if an actor is null, maybe just remove nulls from list or keep uninitialized actors on another list. Also try this with Balls and Enemies, please don't keep every actor on a single list.

Comment: Thumbs up for a check on proximity in order to reduce the order of algorithm from O(N^2)ish to some sort of O(NlogN) order. Threads would help, but a change of strategy is IMO the way to go

Comment: Conditions are evaluated left to right. In a condition with all `&&`'s the first false will stop the condition checking. Splitting up the if gets you nothing but more lines.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will do this frequently, consider storing the Enemies and Balls in their own structures (List or Set or whatever works).  That prevents you from looping through actors you don't need, and avoids the instanceof checks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use size(), define a variable
Try not to cast. Try not to uae instanceof.
Maybe, sort lists by zsort or the like so u can, sometimes, start and or stop the loops sooner??

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the (very good) suggestions of the other participant: cache the enemies and projectiles in separate structures, so you don't have to check what they are at all.

Use the time vs space trade-off as much as you can: the standard approach, as hinted by Tomek, in this kind of situations is to reduce the number of checks (=iterations) by pruning the enemies and projectiles that cannot possibly collide within the current frame (they are way to far).

Anyway, a word of advice: go on with the game, complete as much as you can so that it will run correctly (if slowly), and only *then* go for the optimization.

That because

1. by optimizing preemptively in this way you will never finish it
2. you don't know how the final game really will be, perhaps: maybe after finishing 90% of it, you will see some easy chances for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the real improvement to speed would be two collections, one with balls and the other with enemies. As for making it look nicer, you could something like this:

```
for (Actor enemy : getActors()) {
    if (enemy != null && enemy instanceof Enemy) {
        for (Actor ball : getActors()) {
            if (ball != null && ball instanceof Ball && actorsIntersecting(enemy, ball)) {
                ball.remove();
                enemy.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```